# Compare 3 pointers in C++

Tags: c++, pointers

I am new to pointer and I can't clear the errors in my code. Does anyone know why my code getting errors? And please show me how pointer works in this case and how it can be fixed. I do not know why it does not let me post my post with fewer texts so I added this sentence.

```
//Sort 3 numbers
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void reorder(int *a, int *b, int  *c);

int main()
{
    int a, b, c;

    cout << "Enter 3 numbers: " << endl;
    cin >> a;
    cin >> b;
    cin >> c;

    reorder(&a, &b, &c);

    return 0;
}

void reorder(int *a, int *b, int *c)
{
    int *aa = &a, *bb = &b, *cc = &c;
    int *Max;
    int *Mid;
    int *Min;

    Max = max(*aa, *bb, *cc);
    Min = min(*aa, *bb, *cc);

    if(Mid != *aa && Mid != *bb)
    {
        Mid = *cc;
    }

    if(Mid != *bb && Mid != *cc)
    {
        Mid = *aa;
    }

    if(Mid != *cc && Mid != *aa)
    {
        Mid = *bb;
    }

    cout << "Sorted: " << Max << " " << Mid << " " << Min << endl;
}
```

Comment: First you should let us know what error does the compiler flag. Second your are using `Mid` even though it is not initialized. Give it an initial value before using it. Third: do you realize `Mid != *aa` means you are trying to compare a **pointer to an int** with an int?

Comment: _"I do not know why it does not let me post my post with fewer texts so I added this sentence."_ It's supposed to encourage you to write more about your problem. For example, _what_ errors?

Comment: @Hal `Mid` _is_ given a value before it is used.

Comment: @Asteroids `nullptr`? What a great value to have when you will be probably dereferencing it two lines later. I highly doubt OP is looking to compare adresses.

Comment: @Hal I don't know where you're seeing that. There's no `nullptr` anywhere in the code.

Comment: @Hal Ah, now I see - I read `Min` in your comment instead of `Mid` :) It's not `nullptr` but it _does_ have an unspecified value so, yes, that is broken.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but get in the habit of initializing variables with meaningful values. In this case, that means changing `int *Max; ... Max = max(*aa, *bb, *cc);` to `int *Max = max(*aa, *bb, *cc);`. That helps avoid accidentally using uninitialized variables, for example, `Mid` in `if (Mid != *aa && Mid != *bb)`.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> void reorder(int *a, int *b, int *c)
> {
>     int *aa = &a, *bb = &b, *cc = &c;
> ```

The type of `&a` is `int**`. `int**` is not implicitly convertible to `int *`. This program is ill-formed.

> ```
> Max = max(*aa, *bb, *cc);
> ```

The third argument of `max` is a function object that is used to compare the first two arguments. `*cc` is not something that can be called, so it cannot be used as the third argument.

Also, the function would return a reference to integer, which is not convertible to `int*`.

---

```
int *Mid;
```

`Mid` has an indeterminate value.

```
if(Mid != *aa && Mid != *bb)
```

Here you read the indeterminate value. The behaviour of the program would be undefined if it compiled in the first place.

Comment: Oh okay, gotcha!

Answer (score 0):

Here is modified version of your program:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void reorder(int *a, int *b, int  *c);

int main()
{
    int a, b, c;

    cout << "Enter 3 numbers: " << endl;
    cin >> a;
    cin >> b;
    cin >> c;

    reorder(&a, &b, &c);

    return 0;
}

void reorder(int *a, int *b, int *c)
{
    int **aa = &a, **bb = &b, **cc = &c;
    int *Max;
    int *Mid;
    int *Min;

    Max = max(max(*aa, *bb), *cc);
    Min = min(min(*aa, *bb), *cc);

    if(Mid != *aa && Mid != *bb)
    {
        Mid = *cc;
    }

    if(Mid != *bb && Mid != *cc)
    {
        Mid = *aa;
    }

    if(Mid != *cc && Mid != *aa)
    {
        Mid = *bb;
    }

    cout << "Sorted: " << Max << " " << Mid << " " << Min << endl;
}
```

Your program had two problems

1. `int *aa = &a, *bb = &b, *cc = &c;`
2. usage of `std::min (max)` was wrong as third argument is supposed to be compare functor, not pointer

Comment: Now you're comparing pointers, which is _probably_ not what the OP intended. (I realise they used that terminology in their title.)

Comment: Thank you! very helpful